# Monitoring a printer

Tags: c++, monitor, printing

I've written a DLL that monitors our netowork printer. The printer is connected to the server via USB cable. When I print something directly from the server, it displays information about pages sent/printed properly, but when I print something from one of the client computers it only displays its IP, sent/printed is always 0.

I suppose this is a shortcoming of the winspooler API, my question is, is there any way around it?

Here's the code, for what its worth:

```
typedef struct PRINTERMONITOR_API tagPRINTJOBINFO
{
    // name of the machine that printed
    char *machineName;
    // name of the document
    char *document;
    // total pages actually *printed*
    DWORD totalPages;
    // number of pages sent to the printer
    DWORD printed;
    // private: state of the printJob
    BOOL  done;
} printJobInfo_t;

//-------------------------------------------------------
// Function called when the print job event finishes
//-------------------------------------------------------
typedef void (*Callback)(printJobInfo_t *);

//-------------------------------------------------------
// Printer Monitor class
//-------------------------------------------------------
class PrinterMonitor
{
private:

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Handle to the printer.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    HANDLE                  m_hPrinter;

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Handle to the notify object being set when print event
    // occurs.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    HANDLE                  m_hNotify;

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Handle of our worker thread.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    HANDLE                  m_hThread;

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Holds PRINTER_CHANGE_XXX_XXX information about current
    // event.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    DWORD                   m_dwChanged;

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // ID of the worker thread.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    DWORD                   m_dwThreadId;

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Name of the printer.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    char                    *m_pszPrinterName;

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Printer event snooping options.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS  *m_pOptions;

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Output of the event function.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO     *m_pOutPut; 

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Shall we go away?
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    BOOL                    m_fExit;

public:
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Callback function called when the event fires.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    Callback                m_fpCallback;

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // - name of the printer
    // - callback function
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    PrinterMonitor(char *printerName, Callback callback)
    {
        memset(this, 0, sizeof(PrinterMonitor)); // zero me
        m_fpCallback        = callback;
        m_pszPrinterName    = new char[strlen(printerName)];
        strcpy(m_pszPrinterName, printerName);
        m_pOptions          = new PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS;
        m_hThread           = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)PrinterMonitor::StartMonitoring, this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &m_dwThreadId);
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Stop the worker thread and delete some shit
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    ~PrinterMonitor()
    {
        StopMonitor();
        delete(m_pOptions);
        delete[](m_pszPrinterName);
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Run the monitor in a seperate thread
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    void RunMonitor()
    {
        ResumeThread(m_hThread);
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Stop the monitor, noes.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    void StopMonitor()
    {
        m_fExit = true;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Checks if this object is a valid monitor
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    BOOL CheckMonitor()
    {
        if(OpenPrinter(this->m_pszPrinterName, &this->m_hPrinter, NULL))
        {
            if(this->m_hPrinter != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                ClosePrinter(this->m_hPrinter);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // The worker thread proc
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    static void WINAPI StartMonitoring(void *thisPtr)
    {

        PrinterMonitor* pThis = reinterpret_cast<PrinterMonitor*>(thisPtr);

        if(OpenPrinter(pThis->m_pszPrinterName, &pThis->m_hPrinter, NULL))
        {
            WORD wJobFields[5];
            wJobFields[0]           = JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_STATUS;
            wJobFields[1]           = JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME;
            wJobFields[2]           = JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_TOTAL_PAGES;
            wJobFields[3]           = JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PAGES_PRINTED;
            wJobFields[4]           = JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT;

            PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE rOptions[1];
            rOptions[0].Type    = JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE;
            rOptions[0].pFields = &wJobFields[0];
            rOptions[0].Count   = 5;

            pThis->m_pOptions->Count    = 1;
            pThis->m_pOptions->Version  = 2;
            pThis->m_pOptions->pTypes   = rOptions;
            pThis->m_pOptions->Flags    = PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_REFRESH;

            if((pThis->m_hNotify = 
                FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(pThis->m_hPrinter, 0, 0, pThis->m_pOptions)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                while(pThis->m_hNotify != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && !pThis->m_fExit)
                {
                    if(WaitForSingleObject(pThis->m_hNotify, 10) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                    {
                        FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(pThis->m_hNotify, &pThis->m_dwChanged, (LPVOID)pThis->m_pOptions, (LPVOID*)&pThis->m_pOutPut);

                        printJobInfo_t info = {0};
                        for (unsigned int i=0; i < pThis->m_pOutPut->Count; i++)
                        {
                            PRINTER_NOTIFY_INFO_DATA data = pThis->m_pOutPut->aData[i];

                            if(data.Type == JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE)
                            {
                                switch(data.Field
                                {
                                    case JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_PAGES_PRINTED:
                                        {
                                            info.printed = data.NotifyData.adwData[0];
                                        }
                                        break;

                                    case JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_MACHINE_NAME:
                                        {
                                            LPSTR name = (LPSTR) data.NotifyData.Data.pBuf;
                                            unsigned int length = strlen(name); 
                                            info.machineName = new char[length];
                                            strcpy(info.machineName, name);                                         
                                        }
                                        break;

                                    case JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_TOTAL_PAGES:
                                        {
                                            info.totalPages = data.NotifyData.adwData[0];
                                        }
                                        break;

                                    case JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_DOCUMENT:
                                        {
                                            LPSTR document = (LPSTR) data.NotifyData.Data.pBuf;
                                            unsigned int length = strlen(document);
                                            info.document = new char[length];
                                            strcpy(info.document, document);                                            
                                        }
                                        break;

                                    case JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_STATUS:
                                        {
                                            if(data.NotifyData.adwData[0] & JOB_STATUS_PRINTED)
                                            {
                                                info.done = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if(info.done)
                        {
                            pThis->m_fpCallback(&info);

                            delete[](info.document);
                            delete[](info.machineName);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(pThis->m_hPrinter != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                    ClosePrinter(pThis->m_hPrinter);

                if(pThis->m_hNotify != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                    FindClosePrinterChangeNotification(pThis->m_hNotify);

            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. The network printer sends only basic info if it was added automatically by windows.

Adding the printer manually fixed the problem.